# How do I copy over all secrets from one Azure Keyvault to another using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

We recently found ourselves needing to copy over every single secret (name and value) from one Azure KeyVault to a newly created one. I found ways to restore the secrets from a backup, but we didn't have a backup. Is there a Powershell script that can just loop through every name/value combo in a source vault and copy it to a destination vault?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

this is just too triggering (no offense), here's a more "powershelly" version:

```bsh
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$sourceVaultName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$destVaultName
)

Connect-AzAccount

$secretNames = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName).Name
$secretNames.foreach{
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $destVaultName -Name $_ `
        -SecretValue (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName -Name $_).SecretValue
}
```

Just to sum it up:

Parameters are mandatory with this change and you can tab complete them, so you dont have to remember which one is first.
Using `foreach` is a bit cleaner than using `do\while` (certainly less cognitive effort).
You dont have to cast values to text and encrypt it back, you can just use encrypted value to assign it to new secret

Comment: cool that looks way neater--i don't write a lot of powershell (if you couldn't tell) so thanks for cleaning it up!

Answer (score 8):

The script can be translated to the new coolness of az.cli

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$sourceVaultName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$sourceSubscription,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$destVaultName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$descriptionSubscription
)

# az login
if($sourceSubscription){
    az account set --subscription $sourceSubscription
}

Write-Host 'Reading secrets ids from' $sourceVaultName
$secretNames = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $sourceVaultName  -o json --query "[].name"  | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Host 'Reading secrets values'
$secrets = $secretNames | % {
    $secret = az keyvault secret show --name $_ --vault-name $sourceVaultName -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        name  = $_;
        value = $secret.value;
    }
}
Write-Host 'writing secrets'

if($descriptionSubscription){
    az account set --subscription $descriptionSubscription
}

$secrets.foreach{
    az keyvault secret set --vault-name $destVaultName --name $_.name  --value  $_.value
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? The name parameter is not outputted in the LIST command. I could not get this to work.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/3499

Comment: yup, @markwilde, I test it by saving in a .ps1 file and running the script supplying the parameters. It run correctly and cloned my KVs

Comment: This DOES not work, it fails silently as the name is not exported. 
The fix is reasonably simple though
```
$secretNames = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $sourceVaultName  -o json --query "[].id" | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring($_.LastIndexOf('/') +1 ) }

Comment: @GavinB the original line worked just fine for me.

Comment: I also used the following to backup the secret after the reading secret values part:

$secrets.foreach{
    Write-Host "$($sourceVaultName)-$($_.name)" 
    az keyvault secret backup --file "$($sourceVaultName)-$($_.name).secretbackup" --name $_.name --vault-name $sourceVaultName --subscription $sourceSubscription
}

Answer (score 7):

This is for those who came here looking for a python solution:

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient  # pip install azure-keyvault-secrets
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential  # pip install azure-identity

source_vault_url = "https://sourcevault.vault.azure.net"
destination_vault_url = "https://destvault.vault.azure.net/"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(
    exclude_cli_credential=False
    , exclude_environment_credential=True
    , exclude_managed_identity_credential=True
    , exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=True
    , exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True
    , exclude_interactive_browser_credential=True
)

source_client = SecretClient(vault_url=source_vault_url, credential=credential)
destination_client = SecretClient(vault_url=destination_vault_url, credential=credential)

key_list = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

# Get secrets from the source key vault
credentials = {}
for key in key_list :
    credentials[key] = source_client.get_secret(key).value

# Set secrets in the destination  key vault
for key, value in credentials.items():
    print(f"Creating a secret called '{key}' with the value '{value}' ...")
    destination_client.set_secret(key, value)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Script works well for me. Ensure that you fill out the `key_list` list with the keys you'd like to transfer. Also a good note is that this is for two key vaults within the _same_ Azure subscription!

Answer (score 5):

There is now!

```
import-module AzureRM.keyvault

$sourceVaultName = $args[0]
$destVaultName = $args[1]

Connect-AzureRmAccount

#unfortunately you can only access secret values one at a time, by name. so this gets the names first
$names = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName | select Name)

$i=0
do {
   $rawSecret = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName -Name $names[$i].Name).SecretValueText
   $AKVsecret = ConvertTo-SecureString $rawSecret -AsPlainText -Force
   Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $destVaultName -Name $names[$i].Name -SecretValue $AKVsecret
   $i++
} while($i -lt $names.length)
```

You can call it using

> script.ps1 source-keyvault-name dest-keyvault-name

Answer (score 5):

I started with @4c74356b41's answer, but made a couple changes. I didn't want to copy the certificates across since that doesn't really work well (it copies them as secrets, and they don't work at all cross-region), and I wanted to preserve the ContentType properties as well:

```ps
$sourceVaultName = "<source vault>"
$destVaultName = "<dest vault>"

$secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName
$secrets | ? { $_.ContentType -ne "application/x-pkcs12" } | % {
    $secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName -Name $_.Name
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $destVaultName -Name $secret.Name -SecretValue $secret.SecretValue -ContentType $secret.ContentType
}
```

Comment: worked for me as well. Thanks. Any advice how to copy Keys as well?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [set of powershell scripts](https://github.com/corrupt-code/keyvault-clone) to clone key vaults from one subscription to another. Hope it make some help.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you just copying all secrets from a keyvault and rewriting them in the very same keyvault?

Comment: @Sartigan No, I am making this dynamic so you can specify name of the new key vault and the script will copy it there

Answer (score 1):

Very simple script to copy secret from one vault to another:

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]$oldKeyVault,
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]$newKeyVault
)

#Display Secrets in New Key Vault
Write-Host 'Secrets in New Key Vault BEFORE Sync'
$newSecrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $newKeyVault
foreach($newSecret in $newSecrets)
{
    $newSecretDetails = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $newKeyVault -Name $newSecret.Name

    Write-Host 'New Secret: Name='$newSecretDetails.Name

    #Uncomment below if you need to check values
    #Write-Host 'New Secret: Name='$newSecretDetails.Name ': Value=' $newSecretDetails.SecretValueText
}

Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''

#Display Secrets in New Old Vault
Write-Host 'Secrets in Old Key Vault before Sync'
$oldSecrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $oldKeyVault
foreach($oldSecret in $oldSecrets)
{
    $oldSecretDetails = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $oldKeyVault -Name $oldSecret.Name

    Write-Host 'Old Secret: Name='$oldSecretDetails.Name

    #Uncomment below if you need to check values   
    #Write-Host 'Old Secret: Name='$oldSecretDetails.Name ': Value=' $oldSecretDetails.SecretValueText
}

Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''

#Sync Key Vault
Write-Host 'Syncing Vaults'
$oldSecrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $oldKeyVault
foreach($oldSecret in $oldSecrets)
{
    $oldSecretDetails = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $oldKeyVault -Name $oldSecret.Name    
    $secureStringKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $oldSecretDetails.SecretValueText -AsPlainText -Force    
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $newKeyVault -Name $oldSecretDetails.Name -SecretValue $secureStringKey
    Write-Host 'Secret Copied to New Key Vault: Name = ' $oldSecretDetails.Name
}

Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''

#Display Secrets in New Key Vault
Write-Host 'Secrets in New Key Vault AFTER Sync'
$newSecrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $newKeyVault
foreach($newSecret in $newSecrets)
{
    $newSecretDetails = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $newKeyVault -Name $newSecret.Name

    Write-Host 'New Secret: Name='$newSecretDetails.Name

    #Uncomment below if you need to check values  
    #Write-Host 'New Secret: Name='$newSecretDetails.Name ': Value=' $newSecretDetails.SecretValueText
}
```